# how to disable the halo effect of pressing the thumb of the material ui slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

https://material-ui.com/api/slider/

I have tried setting the disabled flag to the entire slider, but the thumb will still have the halo effect when clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.MuiSlider-thumb.Mui-focusVisible, .MuiSlider-thumb:hover {
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

However, it would be nice if you provide a working example next time so we don't have to dig into documentation just to help you. Ty.